# why is services.xml not valid?

Tags: web-services, tomcat, configuration, apache-axis

```
 <service name="CaseCreate" >
<Description>
    Please Type your service description here
</Description>
<messageReceivers>
    <messageReceiver mep="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/wsdl/in-only" class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver" />
    <messageReceiver  mep="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/wsdl/in-out"  class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver"/>
</messageReceivers>
<parameter name="ServiceClass" locked="false">casecreate.CaseCreate</parameter>

<parameter name="InflowSecurity">
   <action>
     <items>UsernameToken</items>
     <passwordCallbackClass>com.myproject.authentication.PWCBHandler</passwordCallbackClass>
    </action>
</parameter>

<module ref="rampart" />

</service>
```

Above is the services.xml that I am trying to use, but eclipse is telling me that this is not a valid sevices.xml file. When I remove the parameter with name="InflowSevcurity" Eclipse does not complain. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Is that the complete file? You don't have a closing </service> element at the end.

Comment: I edited my question. The end service tag was being hidden because I did not indent it, sorry.